# MonoGame Template for Hello World

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, monogame

Which is the most basic MonoGame Template for Visual Studio Professional 2012?  I am creating a Hello World tutorial and want to use the simplest one.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just take a look at each one yourself?

Answer (score -2):

Each one is equally difficult. You want to use the one based on the platform you're using. EX: if using windows 8 use the windows 8 project

Note: Research what a Windows 8 (XAML) project is before using it. For your purposes you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: Why'd i get thumbs-downed?